# PHP map an array of $ amounts to an array of variables and multiply the variable by it's correct amount

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of variables that are each multiplying by a specific amount. I'm looking to map this, so the prices will be easier to update down the road. Any advice on the best way to do that?

```
        $charges = [
            $row->StandardConcretePanel * $standardConcretePanelCharge,
            $row->ADAPedestrianRampWithDomes * 1200,
            $row->ADAPedestrianRampNoDomes * 800,
            $row->OversizedConcretePanel * 340,
            $row->ThickConcretePanel8to10 * 320,
            $row->ThickConcretePanel10to12 * 340,
            $row->ThickConcretePanel12orMore * 360,
            $row->HighEarlyConcretePanels * 1100,
            $row->WinterMix * 75,
            $row->ConcreteBlanketInstallation * 50,
            $row->PanelRemovalFillWithClassV * $panelRemovalCharge,
            $row->BarricadedAndProtectedPanels * 20,
            $row->HighProfilePanelsFrontOfBusinesses * 1100,
            $row->BeforeOrAfterHoursPanels * 1500,
            $row->AlleyOrDrivewayPanelWithIntegralCurb * 1200,
            $row->ConcreteShortLoads4PanelsOrLess * 400,
            $row->CurbAndGutter * 1200
        ];
```

Comment: You can use array_map

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to PHP. I know of that method, but not sure how to go about implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **array_map** with call back function

```
$data = $row;
//Make array which contains all of charges
$charges = array(1200, 800, so on...);

$result = array_map(function ($d, $c){
return $d * $c ;
},$data, $charges);

$var_dump($result);
//Now $result have all of your multiplied result.
```

read more about [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

**Note:** This may misbehave if both array values are not in order as shown in code.